# looking for an IDE for my project developments

Tags: ros, c++, linux, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone.

I am a beginner in ROS. I am trying to control Baxter Robot using ROS in **C++** or **Python** language. I am following the ROS and Baxter Tutorials to learn it. Till now, I am using gedit editor for code writing.But I found that using the gedit  had a problem that I need to switch to terminal for compiling using `Catkin_Make` and switch back to Gedit in case of any error. Apart from that auto-suggestion and debugging are two big challenges, which are not available in the gedit.

I am looking for an IDE, which has at least following support:

1. Suitable for ROS C++ and python code development
2. Auto suggestion while writing the code (like Visual Studio in windows )
3. Line by line debugging support (Functionality to insert breakpoint)
4. Go to definition/Find all references (to see the definitions, header files etc)

in addition,I am using ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234650/looking-for-an-ide-for-my-project-developments/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-18**:
oh, I'm sorry. Yes, it is IDE not IED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you mean `IDE`, not IED. And I recommend you google first; [there have been many threads already about IDEs](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=site%3Aanswers.ros.org+ide+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1